# Visualize energy efficiency level

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, flot

I want to create something like this:

[image: Imgur]

The black line represents a specific value.

I need this visualization within a phonegap-app. I'm using jQuery-mobile and `Flotcharts` for some other stuff.
What would be the simplest way to go? `Flotcharts` does not seem right for this kind of chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a few moments to implement this based in part on @DNS's suggestions above.  I did it without using any plugins, just straight flot magic.

First, I created a gradient background image like the one above (excuse my poor gimp skills).  I then set that to the background of my place holder div. Then I configured flot's grid options to push the xaxis labels up to the center of my div.  Finally I "plotted" a straight line.

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [ 
    {data: [[260,0],[260,100]], color: 'black', lines: {lineWidth:4}} 
],{
    yaxis:{
        show: false
    },
    xaxis:{
        min: 0,
        max: 400
    },
    grid: {
        show: true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        margin: {bottom: 90},
        labelMargin: -90,
        color: 'white'
    }
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaWGS/).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Really nice solution.

I'm using this, but without the image (different screen sizes!)
Instead I'm using CSS for the gradient:
"background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#299a0b), color-stop(50%,#f2e313), color-stop(100%,#c40f0f));"

Answer (score 3):

You can probably do this quite easily by providing the gauge as a background image (either manually or via the [image plugin](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/image/index.html)), turning off the x and y axes, then using [markings](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) to draw the line.

If that doesn't work, you'd need to write it as a plugin.  That would involve providing hooks for drawBackground (to draw the gradient bar), drawSeries (to draw the line), and possibly draw (to override the axes).  For an example of a plugin that replaces Flot's default axes, take a look at [flot-tickrotor](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor).

Take a look at the [Hooks](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#hooks) section of the docs for more info on how this works.

Comment: see my answer above.  The simplicity and extensibility of flot made this about 15 minutes work.  Keep up the great library.