# Gauge chart in Javascript or jQuery Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I'm trying to get a graph that looks like a gauge.

I am already using jQuery Flot for my other charts, so is it possible using Flot or plain Javascript? Can someone help me getting started coding this?

Comment: Edited question looks fine. The solution provided is brilliant and most valuable. Please consider reverting the decision of closing this question.

Answer (score 10):

Here it is only using base `flot` and a background image:

```js
// consts
var minCord = {x: -60, y: -57};
var maxCord = {x: 60, y: -60};
var radius = 90;

$(function() { 
    
    // some calculations
    var startAngle = (6.2831 + Math.atan2(minCord.y, minCord.x));
    var endAngle = Math.atan2(maxCord.y, maxCord.x);
    var degreesSweep = (-endAngle) + startAngle;
        
    var positionOnArc = function(magnitude){
        var numDegrees = degreesSweep * (magnitude/100.0);
        var angle = (startAngle - numDegrees);
        var posX = radius * Math.cos(angle);
        var posY = radius * Math.sin(angle);
        return [posX, posY];
    }  
       
    var options = {
      xaxis: {
          min: -100,
          max: 100,
          show: false
      },
      yaxis: {
          min: -100,
          max: 100,
          show: false
      },
      grid: {
          show: false
      }
    };

    updatePlot = function(){        
        var data = [[0,0],positionOnArc(Math.random() * 100)];
        $('#placeholder').plot([data], options);
        setTimeout(updatePlot, 1000);
    }
    
    updatePlot();
});
```

```css
#placeholder
{
    background-image:url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/6/Z/q/9/9/D/gauge-md.png');
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.1/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YGcYJ/1/).

[image]

Comment: You are awesome, i'm trying, but i did not get anywhere near this. I want to know if i can use the images i pasted in question for background and needle, especially needle. thank you.

Comment: @user2818666, the needle is a `series` line.  Replicating it's appearance would not be difficult.  Do you have the above image without the needle in it?

Comment: Thank you, I'm preparing that. I will update the question in a few minutes. This is what i would like to do. The pointer should point to some angle basing on value in data. If possible before pointing to the value, can the needle just rotate that looks like it is measuring and then stays at a point. Thanks

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for the example! Great work Mark!

Comment: @Mark I'm trying to use my own images for pointer and gauge but i'm unable to get this working properly. Can you please help?

Comment: @user2818666, update your question with your images and desired appearance and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to [Visualize energy efficiency level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976588/visualize-energy-efficiency-level-javascript), except that there is no way to do it using Flot's base options.

As suggested in my answer to that question, you will need to create a plugin that overrides drawBackground, drawSeries, and possibly draw.

Comment: i'm thinking if it's easy to do it without using Flot. What do you think?

Comment: @DNS, I'll take that as challenge, I'm convinced that base options flot can do anything :)

Comment: @DNS looks very complex, but i'm trying, thank you

Comment: @DNS, I found a few moments this afternoon... I'm thinking maybe we should get a "Gauge and Meter" page on the flot example page.

Comment: I've created a example page based on your answers, and next week I'll turn them into a proper plugin in 0.9-work.  Do I have your permission to do that?  Can I credit them to you using your full name?

Comment: @Mark I forgot to call you out in my last comment, about the example page; did you see it?

Comment: @DNS, I saw it now :)  Yes, you have permission.  If you'd like, I wouldn't mind taking a whack at creating the plugin.  The background image came from here: http://www.clker.com/clipart-gauge-for-temperature-2-1.html, and states it's public domain.

Comment: @Mark Sure! I'm actually drawing the backgrounds using primitives, so they scale nicely and image copyrights aren't a problem.  I probably won't have time to finish and push it until Friday, so keep an eye out over the weekend.  I was thinking one gauge plugin with options to control the type (circular v.s. linear; maybe needs a better name than 'type'), colors, etc.

Comment: @DNS this plugin is already in stable version? thanks

Comment: @user2818666 No; it will be in 0.9, but is not yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jqChart's radial gauge. It has the functionality you need:
http://www.jqchart.com/jquery/gauges/RadialGauge/Scale

Disclaimer: I work for jqChart.

Comment: Thanks but it is not open sourced