# Animate needle movement in Gauge chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'm using the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397394/gauge-chart-in-javascript-or-jquery-flot#answer-19411965) to plot a speedometer gauge. This is built with Flot charts. I'm trying to animate the movement of the needle. I want the needle to move slowly from start to end.

Here is what I have so far.

```
updatePlot = function(actual_length){

        var data = [[0,0],positionOnArc(actual_length * 100)];
        $('.gauge-div').delay( 8000 ).plot([data], options);
    
    }

    //The logic: devide one move into 25 moves and add a delay between each move

    var diff_length = Math.abs(prev_move_length - move_length) / 25;

    for(var i=0; i<25; i++) {
        
        if (prev_move_length < move_length) {
            var actual_length = prev_move_length + i * diff_length;
        } else {
            var actual_length = prev_move_length - i * diff_length;
        }
        
        setTimeout(updatePlot(actual_length), 1000);
    }
```

As you can see I'm trying to delay the loop iteration with `setTimeout` and `delay`. But I'm not able to animate the needle movement.

Can you help me to solve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a clever way to use jquery animate (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16857838/760331)) by passing in our own step function, which in this case would move the needle.

Sample code:

```
var updatePlot = function(pos) {        
    var data = [[0,0],positionOnArc(pos)];
    $('#placeholder').plot([data], options);
};

// starting position   
updatePlot(0);

$({foo:0})              // from 0 to
.delay(1000)            // (wait for it..)
.animate({foo:100}, {   // 100
    step: updatePlot,
    duration: 4300      // in 4.3 seconds
}).animate({foo:0}, {   // and back to 0
    step: updatePlot,
    duration: 1000      // in 1 second
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YGcYJ/217/

Comment: Thanks Lian. I'll try this out now!